# Accept two files types in Windows command line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set _SRCDIR=C:\Users\hyea\Desktop\Testing\Text Files
set _DSTDIR=C:\Users\hyea\Desktop\Testing\Text Files\TargetFolder

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d "!_SRCDIR!\*.COS"') do (
type "%_SRCDIR%\header.txt" > "!_DSTDIR!\%%f"
type "!_SRCDIR!\%%f" >> "!_DSTDIR!\%%f"
)
```

I have the above code which concatenates the header file with the contents of the text file which have an extension of `.COS`.

Just wondering how would I go about adding another file extension to that of `.RCS`, so both `.COS` and `.RCS` are picked up.

How would the code look like?

Comment: `dir /b /a-d "!_SRCDIR!\*.COS"` --> `dir /b /a-d "!_SRCDIR!\*.COS" "!_SRCDIR!\*.RCS"`

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt seem to do anthing, is this right:  @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set _SRCDIR=C:\Users\hyea\Desktop\Testing\Text Files
set _DSTDIR=C:\Users\hyea\Desktop\Testing\Text Files\TargetFolder

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d "!_SRCDIR!\*.COS" --> dir /b /a-d "!_SRCDIR!\*.COS" "!_SRCDIR!\*.RCS"') do (
    type "%_SRCDIR%\header.txt" > "!_DSTDIR!\%%f"
    type "!_SRCDIR!\%%f" >> "!_DSTDIR!\%%f"
)

Comment: No, I meant replacing the part left to the "-->" in your code by the part right to it...

Comment: [Windows command line is **not** DOS](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: Thank you @aschipfl, its worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dir` command accepts multiple path/file name/pattern parameters, so simply add the second file type to the command line like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_SRCDIR=C:\Users\hyea\Desktop\Testing\Text Files"
set "_DSTDIR=C:\Users\hyea\Desktop\Testing\Text Files\TargetFolder"

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d "!_SRCDIR!\*.COS" "!_SRCDIR!\*.RCS"') do (
type "%_SRCDIR%\header.txt" > "!_DSTDIR!\%%f"
type "!_SRCDIR!\%%f" >> "!_DSTDIR!\%%f"
)
```

In addition, I improved the `set` command lines and put quotation marks around the whole assignment expressions, which avoids trouble with potential special characters, but does not include the `""` in the values of the variables.

Comment: Thank you, whats the best code to use to delete all the content of the TargetFolder in a seperate bat. file?

Comment: Would it be del C:\Users\hyea\Desktop\Testing\Text Files\TargetFolder\*.*  however ideally just want to delete .cos and .rcs files

Comment: `del`, like `dir`, accepts multiple file spec.s either, so: `del "C:\Users\hyea\Desktop\Testing\Text Files\TargetFolder*.COS" "C:\Users\hyea\Desktop\Testing\Text Files\TargetFolder*.RCS"`...